# Adding divs between links in php menu

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I want to add a div between the links in my Wordpress menu (not on the ends, just in between). I am using the following code to bring in my menu:

html

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'main-nav', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

functions.php

```
/* Register 'primary' navigation */
function wptutsplus_register_theme_menu() {
register_nav_menu( 'primary', 'Main Navigation Menu' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wptutsplus_register_theme_menu' );
```

The output I'm looking for is the following:

```
<a href="#"> link 1 </a>
<div class="divider"></div>
<a href="#"> link 2 </a>
<div class="divider"></div>
<a href="#"> link 2 </a>
```

Comment: Means do you want to wrap a tag with div??

Comment: I want it to output link1  'div'   link2   'div'  link 3 etc. the div being the same acting as a seperater

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you get result  https://www.screencast.com/t/APLrCeHCxLU.

You can try following code:-

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'main-nav','theme_location' => 'primary','after' => '<div class="divider"></div>') ) );
```

Comment: Close i guess, that puts a div inside the link, I just want to put a div after the link. and then the next link, the another div, then a link, etc. Just in between links

Comment: It will be better understood if you will give html proper format for that exactly you want.So i can better help you as i gave you in above screenshot.

Comment: I updated my question to hopefully help understand my question

Comment: I also Updated my answer you can try this one. I hope this is your result.

Comment: Awesome, that works for the most part. As I mentioned I was hoping to get it so they only appear in between the links (so the last one would have it) but this is close